# Change color of white line between filename and editor on Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

As you can see below, there is this annoying white line under the filename. How would I change its color to black? I am using the Atom One Dark Pro theme.

I believe it shouldn't be too complicated, as VS Code is pretty customizable.

[image: White line under filename]

Comment: change a possible theme color to red until you hit the white line, then make that name transparent or equal to workspace background, it shows you the active tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open Command Palette and find "Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)"
2. It'll open `settings.json`. In the file, add the following entry:

   ```json
   "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
     "[One Dark Pro]": {
       "tab.activeBorder": "#292c33"  // <-- Change color here
     }
   }
   ```

Preview:

[image: Preview]

Reference: [Theme Color | Visual Studio Code Extension API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#editor-groups-tabs)